# Internet & Play Store problem on Micromax Yureka on Lollipop

Tags: micromax-yu-yureka

Yesterday, I got an update to upgrade my Micromax Yureka mobile to Cyanogenmod 12 which upgrades the Android version to Lollipop.

After this upgrade, following issues came into existence:

- Internet is not working
- Play store is not working
- Apps are not downloading

These issues didn't occur on KitKat. Please give me a solution.

Comment: Please don't add your phone number and all that. That is not required, as most of the users here come from different countries. Replies are added online.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove your google account and add it again. I did it today with my Yureka and now it is working seamlessly. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the latest version of **Gapps** (Google Apps) for fix this error.

> **Play store is not working Apps is not**

but, for not working `Net`, its better to contact with rom developer for fix this at newest version.

also, you can try to `Factory reset` or wipe (without losing data) with Custom recovery.(Mostly, last solution, will be fix this error )

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps:

1. Try to remove your google account and add it again.
2. Try applying a factory reset.
3. If none of them work, contact the developers and let them know about this issue.
4. And meanwhile, flash your device with the previous version of your ROM, (in your case, I guess it's lollipop 5.0).

I hope this might have been helpful.