# Laptop unable to detect Micromax Yureka after Lollipop upgrade for data transfer

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb, connection-issues, micromax

After the Lollipop upgrade on Micromax Yureka, data transfer from mobile to the laptop is not working. The laptop is unable to detect the device.

Comment: Looks like that device has trouble running Lollipop. It's not the most widespread device, still we got a lot of reports here: [My Yureka phone is restarts automatically while sending any files](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106665/16575) / [Internet & Play Store problem on Micromax Yureka on Lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106575/16575) / [Yureka issues since updating to Lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106581/16575) are some examples, [see here for more](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=yureka+lollipop).

Comment: Does you computer detects your device in Device Manager? Do you see a charging light coupled with a USB Connection notification in device? If you do see, does your system detect it in other mode like PTP? Please troubleshoot a bit more and add details here [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Download drivers from the official support site and install on your computer.
Go to phone settings and search for USB connection mode. Set to mass storage.
Connect to your computer via USB.
You could also smuse Yureka PC Suite to transfer data. Google for that, install. It will install drivers automatically and your device will show up.

If it still doesn't show up, try another USB port.

Still no? Try on another computer with the software and drivers installed.

Otherwise, contact support.